# Jenkins: send email when the build is in progress

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is it possible to send mail in Jenkins, when build is in progress?

I have tried to explore the email-ext plugin in Jenkins, but I want to know at what time during the build, that this plugin sends mail.

Comment: have you tested, and checked the time of the email?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you can a least add a build step which calls a program thats send a mail. So it is possible, but if there is a "quick" solution ...

Comment: What's your use case? If you just want to know what the default triggers are, play around with the configuration options in a testjob. Don't forget to check the advanced configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can send mails before executing your script using pre build step and after your script using post build actions.along with this you can also send email basing on some condition in the script.